# zkoss pure java tutorials

Tags: java, zk

i am searching is there is any good tutorial for zkoss in pure java i searched i dint get any one and i need to know how to create an combo box in zkoss and add and items to combo box using java

Answer (score 6):

ZK defined the technology of **"pure JAVA ZK"** as Richlet

I found a good document [on Richlets here.](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/Richlet)

All you need is implement the interface and create your page directly

```
package org.zkoss.zkdemo;

import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Page;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.GenericRichlet;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.*;
import org.zkoss.zul.*;

public class TestRichlet extends GenericRichlet {
//Richlet//
  public void service(Page page) {
    page.setTitle("Richlet Test");

    final Window w = new Window("Richlet Test", "normal", false);
    new Label("Hello World!").setParent(w);
    final Label l = new Label();
    l.setParent(w);

    final Button b = new Button("Change");
    b.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK,
        new EventListener() {
            int count;
            public void onEvent(Event evt) {
                l.setValue("" + ++count);
            }
        });
    b.setParent(w);

    w.setPage(page);
  }
}
```